# What am I doing wrong with this addition code?

Tags: javascript

```
  var addition=function(num){
    var sumSoFar=0;  
    for(var i=1;i<=num;i++)
        {
         sumSoFar+=num[i];
         return sumSoFar;
         }
         };
        console.log(addition(5));
```

I wrote this with a while loop a little bit ago. It supposed to take a random (num) and return the sum of all numbers from 1 to (num) Im just not figuring out what im doing wrong with the for loop

Comment: Indent your code properly and read what each line does and when.

Comment: `num` is not an `Array`

Comment: Why use loop for that, I wonder, if you can just `num * (num + 1) / 2`?

Answer (score 1):

inside the for loop you are returning he sum, so you just return 1!

do

```
  var addition=function(num){
    var sumSoFar=0;  
    for(var i=1;i<=num;i++)
        {
         sumSoFar+=i;

         }
    return sumSoFar;
   };
   console.log(addition(5));
```

also if you just need the sum of i from 1 to n do:

```
  var addition=function(num){
      return (1+num) * num / 2;
  };
```

and read on [Arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

Comment: The `num` variable isn't an array, so you can't perform `num[i]`

Comment: @Vallentin what num[i]? :)

Comment: @Vallentin indeed i did :)

Answer (score 0):

Your return is inside the for loop - it should be outside.

Answer (score 0):

You've put a `return` statement in the middle of the loop. That will cause the function to return on the first pass through there.

If `num` is a number, then `num[i]` doesn't mean anything. You just need to add `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Do u want to do this:

```
var addition=function(num){
var sumSoFar=0;  
for(var i=1;i<=num;i++)
    {
     sumSoFar+=i;//will add the loop varible to get sum

     }
     return sumSoFar;//also function can return a value only once and not in a loop
     };
```